# Using a union in a struct that contains either pre-calculated or calculatable results

Tags: c++, data-structures, unions

So I have a struct I need to create. Essentially its purpose is that an array of these structs will be returned from a variety of functions. All of these structs will be gathered (maybe a few hundred) and I will then need the normal for the least of them.

So to sort of summarise I have a situation where there will be many of these structs however the normal value will only be needed for one of them.

As such I was trying to create a struct that captures this idea. That way the one chosen struct can either contain its normal or a method to calculate it. As such I designed the following struct:

```
struct result {
    float t;
    bool calculated; // Tells whether to use result.normal.norm or result.norm.calculate()
    union normal {
        float2 norm;
        float2 (*calculate)();
    };
};
```

Is this the proper way to express this idea?

*For examples sake some of these normal calculations might involve some calculations like trig to figure out a normal on a complex curved surface. We would only want to calculate this if absolutely necessary.

Comment: The *proper way* to express an idea in code is a matter of opinion. There are always many ways to express any idea. However, that is certainly *one way* to express the idea.

Comment: My answers would be different for C or C++. It's generally a good idea to tag just one language, unless the question is specifically about a difference between languages or interaction between code using different languages.

Comment: @aschepler my mistake I figured there would not be a difference.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your code and your description. Your description suggests that you need to pick one struct, then get the normal for that struct (no indication of how that normal is obtained). Your code suggests that the normal is either known or calculable (no indication of needing the normal for only one struct). A third idea that occurs to me is that you might be trying to do a lazy calculation -- not calculating until needed, but once needed, caching the result in case it is needed a second time. Which of these is what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

(I don't believe you've provided enough context to fully answer your question, but I'll try based on what you've given me.)

> Is this the proper way to express this idea?

Since you seem to be concerned with performance - probably not. Calling a function through a function pointer is (edit:) often expensive. What's more, that function doesn't even get the `t` field's value when you call it... so this will probably not even work.

What should you do, then?

First, figure out if this is even a pain point w.r.t. performance. Don't just optimize this because there's a potential for optimization.

Assuming this is useful to optimize - try avoiding this whole materialization-of-results. Instead, determine which float needs its norm, then be willing to spend some effort getting that norm; it won't be that bad since you'll only be doing work for one piece of data rather than all of them.

PS - No need to use unions these days, we have [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) in C++17. The would save you the boolean, too.

Comment: Why is calling a function through a function pointer expensive?

Comment: @J.Doe A typical function call would be done with a relative address, function pointers require exact addresses which will force you to use a far jump which is slower for the CPU to handle. The performance difference is probably negligible in any modern workflow.

Comment: @J.Doe: Many compiler optimizations cannot be performed when the compiler doesn't know which function is actually going to get called.